# How to prevent user from accessing complete source of angularjs application

Tags: angularjs

If an angularJs application is created and hosted the user will have access to all source since it is getting rendered there can at least part of the source be prevented from user access directly. If so how do I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some combination of lazy loading, authentication and server-side rendering...

See http://wassimchegham.com/blog/angular-2-universal-isomorphic-server-rendering-ng2-survey-results

Answer (score 0):

For what I know, this is not possible since the browser needs to download the javascript files to run it in the browser js environment.

The only thing that can somewhat help is that you can uglify the javascript code to make it nearly unreadable. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify